# How do I execute 'like' statement using mongoose

Tags: regex, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, sql-like

I have some data here:
`{ _id: 1, url: "romeojuliet" }`
`{ _id: 2, url: "romeojuliet2" }`
`{ _id: 3, url: "oromeojuliet" }`

This is my current code

```
exports.searchUrl = function(req, res) {
  var url = req.body.url;

  Content.find({ 'url': /^url/i}, function(err, doc) {
  var returnValue = doc;
  if(doc == null) {
    returnValue = {};
  }
  if (err) return next(err)
    return res.send(returnValue);  
  });
};
```

Expect that `req.body.url` is "romeojuliet"
From that code I actually want to show all the data that contains "romeojuliet%",
in that case the **_id 1** and **2** will **appear**.

Is it possible?

Comment: Is there any link that explain fully about RegExp in mongoose?

Answer (score 0):

Make this:

```
exports.searchUrl = function(req, res) {
  var url = req.body.url;

  Content.find({ 'url': /^romeojuliet/i}, function(err, doc) {
  var returnValue = doc;
  if(doc == null) {
    returnValue = {};
  }
  if (err) return next(err)
    return res.send(returnValue);  
  });
};
```